# Неопределенное поведение при определении/объявлении внешних глобальных констант

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

В книге "Программирование: принципы и практика использования С++" приводится следующий пример:

```
// file f1.cpp
int x1 = 1;
int y1 = x1+2; // y1 becomes 3


 // file f2.cpp
extern int y1;
int y2 = y1+2; //UB, y2 becomes 2 or 5
```

То есть неизвестно, в каком порядке будут инициализированы глобальные переменные. Стоит ли ожидать аналогичного поведения при использовании глобальных констант?:

```
// file f1.cpp
int x1 = 1;
const int y1 = x1+2; // y1 becomes 3


 // file f2.cpp
extern const int y1;
int y2 = y1+2; //UB???
```

И почему UB возникает вообще? Ведь переменная/константа во втором файле явно объявлена, но не инициализирована, а значит чтобы "узнать" её значение нужно обратиться к определению, а в этом случае y1 явно = 3.
Ведь когда программа вызывает функцию, которая объявлена в первом файле, но определена во втором, она ведь не предполагает, что тело функции пусто (равно нулю), как это происходит в случае с внешними глобальными переменными.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, вы должны в файле `f1.cpp` указать, что константа имеет внешнее связывание

```
extern const int y1 = x1+2; // y1 becomes 3
```

иначе она будет не видна в файле `f2.cpp`, так как константы в C++ имеют внутреннее связывание.

Что касается вашего вопроса, то это не имеет значения, является ли переменная константой или нет. Проблема связана с тем, что не определен порядок инициализации статической памяти у модулей.

Что касается функций, то редактор связей просто проставляет адреса для внешних символов. К самим же функциям обращение идет во время выполнения. Поэтому, например, статические переменные функции инициализируются при вызове функции.

Comment: а межмодульная оптимизация не уберёт сложение?

Comment: @pavel Я не знаю, что такое "межмодульная оптимизация". Такого понятия  в стандарте нет.

Comment: @jumpjet67 Смотрите мой обновленный ответ. Редактор связей подставляет адреса функций в точках их вызовов.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, смотрите, как я понимаю extern позволяет _объявить_ переменную, а значит (насколько я понимаю смысл _объявления_) ей даже не выделится память. Как же компилятор так, сходу, делает вывод о том, что она = 0 (ведь в её _определении_ она (y1) = 3) Предлагаю перейти в чат

Comment: @jumpjet67 Статическая память обычно инициализируется в два этапа. Сначала она инициализируется нулем, а затем конкретными значениями. Нулем статическую память, как правило, инициализирует загрузчик программы. Порядок же инициализации конкретными значениями переменных в каждой единице трансляции не определен. Тем не менее адреса всех объектов известны. Вопрос состоит в том, будет ли обращение по адресу в памяти, до ее конкретной инициализации или после.

Comment: @jumpjet67  Более того загрузчик имеет право перемещать секции программы в памяти, независимо от того, как вы их выстроили при вызове редактора связей.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, т.е. компилятор "просматривает" текст программы на наличие глобальных переменных, и независимо от того, как они объявлены/определены, выделяет нужное кол-во статической памяти, инициализируя её нулём? А extern нужен лишь для того, чтобы связать объявление/определение переменной в разных файлах?

Comment: @jumpjet67 Компилятор для каждой единицы трансляции строит таблицу внешних символов. Редактор связей определяет, сколько на самом деле имеется внешних символов и соответственно вычисляет необходимый объем памяти. Загрузчик программы выделяет эту память при загрузке программы и инициализирует ее нулем. Далее уже когда программа загружена, то происходит инициализация этих статических переменных конкретными значениями.